# How to download web table using Python or R script

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

I am trying to download data from below link.
link: https://dataminer2.pjm.com/feed/act_sch_interchange

i used below python code not working.

```
import urllib.request 
from pprint import pprint 
from html_table_parser import HTMLTableParser 
import pandas as pd

def url_get_contents(url):
 req = urllib.request.Request(url=url)
 f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
 return f.read()

xhtml = url_get_contents('https://dataminer2.pjm.com/feed/act_sch_interchange') 
p = HTMLTableParser() 
p.feed(xhtml)
pprint(p.tables[1])
print("\n\nPANDAS DATAFRAME\n") 
print(pd.DataFrame(p.tables[1]))
```

---

I am beginner in coding pls let me know if i did any wrong in the code.

addition to download the data i want to download the table by changing dates and text boxes.

is this possible? any help, thank in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvQPH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0",
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "d408630449804e23b07148259c96b24a",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
}

r = requests.get("https://api.pjm.com/api/v1/act_sch_interchange", headers=headers)

df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()["items"])
```

If you want to change date, you should change url:

> url = "https://api.pjm.com/api/v1/act_sch_interchange?rowCount=25&sort=datetime_beginning_utc&order=Asc&startRow=1&isActiveMetadata=true&fields=actual_flow,datetime_beginning_ept,datetime_beginning_utc,datetime_ending_ept,datetime_ending_utc,inadv_flow,sched_flow,tie_line&datetime_beginning_ept=1/27/2021 00:00to2/1/2021 23:59"

Comment: Thanks a lot dimay, your code is perfectly working.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the HTTP data from said website will unfortunately not give you the data.

What the page contains (simplified version) is some very basic HTML and JS code that loads the data in the background.

One way to visualize what gets loaded by the webiste is to use Chrome's developer mode (Settings->developer mode). Having had a quick look (no, just putting the URL in the browser will not work), it seems that in order to load the JSON data that contains the data you will need to construct HTTP requests containing the correct headers (e.g. `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`) to directly query the API where the data is made accessible.

Comment: Thanks Josep for your inputs. sorry i did not try your suggestion as i got right code for my request in following thread. Thanks